# Ajax read HTML after fully processed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load the HTML content of a webpage outside of my domain, which I can do just fine using functionality provided by this jQuery plugin: http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/. However, when I print out the HTML there are pieces missing, which I assume is because the ajax request gets the HTML before the page is fully loaded. When I say "pieces missing," I mean that some tags that should have innerHTML in fact have none. Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: "http://siriusxm.com/bpm",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    timeout: 5000
});
```

The crossOrigin attribute is from the plugin I mentioned. I get the same behavior with and without the timeout (and strangely, it doesn't seem as though the timeout is doing anything at all--when I check the console, it logs `data` pretty much immediately).

Is there a way to wait until the page is fully loaded before getting the content? For what it's worth, this is all part of a chrome extension I'm developing, so if there's anything else code-wise you might need just ask.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried your code, and compared the ajax results with the source of that page. No significant difference. And by that I mean one version had "%2Fg" replaced with "..." in one of the meta tags.

Comment: Huh, interesting. So then I guess that would point at this being an issue with it being part of a chrome extension, would you agree?

Comment: Yeah I guess so--I have no experience writing Chrome extensions, so I can't say for sure. But if you want to see for yourself, just open up devtools right on this page, go to the console, paste in the JS from ajax-cross-origin, then paste in the code from your post. Compare with view-source of "http://siriusxm.com/bpm". I saved them both to my desktop and ran `diff ~/Desktop/sirius-src.html ~/Desktop/sirius-src-ajax.html` in my terminal to see the difference.

Comment: Ah well there's the thing. The source code for siriusxm.com/bpm doesn't have what I'm looking for either--I also get identical results from my code and the page source. Check my comment under Caff3in3fr33's answer for exactly what I want to extract. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to your comments, the information you're looking for is just the Now Playing artist and Song, which you won't be able to get by loading just the source of the main page.

To find the data you're looking for just open up your Chrome DevTools, go to the network tab, and Refresh to see all requests on the page.

It looks like this is the request you want, you just need to update the timestamp every minute:
`http://www.siriusxm.com/metadata/pdt/en-us/json/channels/thebeat/timestamp/08-12-03:48:00`

Just parse that json and grab what you need. Of course they can always change the location or format of the file, but for right now that's what it is.

Comment: Well hell, look at that. Thanks a bunch, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Just curious, how did you know to use that URL?

Comment: I had the devtools network tab open for awhile, and they're making that same request every minute.

Answer (score 0):

If the console log is showing all of the data you're looking for then the ajax call should be fine.

Any code in the success callback will be ran after the ajax call, so just use JQuery in the success callback function to insert data into the html.  All I see there now is the console.log(data) unless you've removed some code.

The timeout just gives the ajax call a set amount of time to complete before it "times out", in other words it tells it to stop waiting after the set amount of time.

Comment: Well my misunderstanding of the timeout functionality explains why it didn't appear to be doing anything. And my goal is not to insert data into the HTML; I'm simply trying to read it. Specifically, I want the innerHTML of the two `p` tags with class names "onair-pdt-artist" and "onair-pdt-song." But when I log `data` those two tags look like this: `<p class="onair-pdt-artist"></p><p class="onair-pdt-song"></p>` But there should be text within them like this: `<p class="onair-pdt-artist">Michael Jackson</p><p class="onair-pdt-song">Billie Jean</p>`

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense. The main source of the page is loading it as `<p class="onair-pdt-artist"></p>`. Which means they must have JS (likely an ajax request) to fetch that data and then update that `<p>` tag. This way they aren't reloading the whole page whenever the song changes, just fetching the new data and replacing it.

Comment: I see, so then do you know of a way to overcome this problem or am I SOL?

Comment: I'm sorry I thought you were trying to use the data.  Perhaps there's a php call you could make to get the data from siriusxm?

Comment: Looks like @cyk answered my question, but thanks for your help Caff3in3fr33!